Redirect Issue on a link from the client side
I have implemented header menu  using the WordPress menu tab and it is working correctly on my local pc but client from usa and other countries have frequently complaint that the sales button on the header keep sending them to dating site. I am unable to find the issue on my local pc or even checking through VPN. Is there any solution or way to find out the virus error so could work on fixing the bug?

If it's only happening on their computer it may be that THEY have a virus.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can scan your website with https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/
This website will check if there is any malicious code present on your live server.

I did the scan and the result were that the site has no malware. Still, the client has said that button frequently redirect to dating site not every time. Is there any another way to root out the problem?
